# I have a problem with a program for a library

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a class that is creating books, and also a class where it is going to save the books in an array, but I have to make a method that prints all the books that have the same title but of a different year, and it happens to me that this failing from code what it does is that it duplicates some books, is there a way to prevent this from happening to me?

```
void buscarNombre(string elemento){
            int i, j;
            int largo = 0;
            bool primeraVez = true;
            largo=contadorLibros();
            
            for(i=0;i<largo-1;i++){
                if (vec[i].getTitulo() == elemento){
                    for(j=i+1;j<largo;j++){
                        if (vec[j].getTitulo() == elemento){
                            if(vec[i].getAnnioImpresion() != vec[j].getAnnioImpresion()){
                                if(primeraVez == true){
                                    cout<<vec[i].toString()<<endl;
                                    primeraVez = false;
                                    
                                }
                                else{
                                    cout<<vec[j].toString()<<endl;
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    primeraVez = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know your native language but if I understand the code correctly:

Assume you have three books with the same title but different publishing dates, lets call the books **A,B,C**.

When you encounter **A** in the first loop, you start looping the second loop. When you encounter **B**, you set `primeraVez = false` to prevent printing again when you encounter **C**; however after the second loop completes, you reset `primeraVez = true`, so when you encounter **B** in the first loop, you reprint the book name in the second loop when you encounter **C**.

You can prevent this by deleting the books you print out from the list or make a `std::set` of books you want to print out and print after the searching completes.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand very well how to do that

Comment: Easiest way would be making a copy of 'vec' and delete the book names you encounter multiple times from the copy. Then print out the elements of the copied array.

Comment: I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

Is it printing the books having same title and are of same year? And why you have the if condition where you are printing the title maybe 'cout' inside else condition is causing that duplicacy.

Comment: is that this helps me if I only have 3 or 4 books that are called the same, if there are more, it duplicates them, and without that the same thing happens to me

Comment: So, is this printing books with same titles and same year and if its so check by debugging whether this is happening for the first element in the vector or the consecutive elements. What you can try is from the second iteration onwards of the outer for loop use 'cout<<vec[j].toString()' since you are setting 'primavez=True' after the first iteration of the outer loop again.